# s there a way to "elevate" the label, over the input Native Base

Tags: react-native, expo, textinput, native-base

Is there a way to "elevate" the label, over the input, I tried with zIndex with no results, any suggestions?
The item with the border is the input, so the label and the input are in a Item component

```
 <Item floatingLabel style={styles.inputItem}>
                            <Label style={styles.inputLabel}>Username</Label>
                            <Input style={styles.inputText}/>
                        </Item>
```

[image]

Comment: Can you please add some code that you have written?

Comment: add `backgroundColor: '#ffffff'` and some padding to your `inputLabel` style.

Comment: not working. I already tried

Comment: How are you using zIndex, as it should work? Please add your styles to the question

Comment: I tried many time like `zIndex: 1`, `zIndex: 9999`, `zIndex: 99`